# Gradle: Jooq plugin 8.0 on Java 11 with Gradle toolchain (Java17)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jooq, toolchain

I'm trying to get the `nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0` plugin to work in a toolchain environment

Background: Our CI server currently builds using a Java 11 JDK (something I have limited influence over), we are using the Gradle toolchain feature to build our service with Java 17

```
java {
  toolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
  }
}
kotlin {
  jvmToolchain {
    (this as JavaToolchainSpec).languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
  }
}
```

However, when I try to add the jooq gradle plugin, the download of the plugin fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':service'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':service:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0.
     Required by:
         project :service > nu.studer.jooq:nu.studer.jooq.gradle.plugin:8.0
      > No matching variant of nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability nu.studer:gradle-jooq-plugin:8.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
```

I have also tried to add the toolchain directly to the Jooq task

```
  (launcher::set)(javaToolchains.launcherFor {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
  })
  dependsOn(tasks.flywayMigrate)
}
```

but my current assumption is that the configurations only apply once the buildscript is initialized, and the initialization of the buildscript fails due to the build running with Java 11.

I guess I would need to configure the `buildscript {}` to run using a defined toolchain as well, but I haven't found any resources on how to do that. Is this possible, would it fix my build issue, and if yes, how do I do this?

Comment: Experiencing similar issues, have you found any resolution to this problem?

Comment: The only way I found to get this working in the end was to set up a new build agent that runs a Java 17 JDK to initialize the build